# How to pass a Type to sqlite-net Table method?

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I need to do something like this:

```
private void DoStuff(Type itemType)
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    var items = db.Table<itemType>();
    // do stuff here...
    db.Close();
}
```

However, the compiler reports the following error: "itemType is a variable but is used like a Type".

The method signature for Table uses generics:

```
public TableQuery<T> Table<T>() where T : new()
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How about making `DoStuff` generic? `private void DoStuff<T>() { ... db.Table<T>();` ?

Comment: The problem is if you only know the type at runtime, no generics solution is going to help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

itemType is a run-time variable of type System.Type, not a type, so this is of course nonsense. A generic version only makes sense, if you know the types at compile time, i.e.

```
private void DoStuff(TableType itemType)
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    var items = db.Table<TableType>();
    // do stuff here...
    db.Close();
}
```

To apply `DoStuff()` to different types you could use overloading. Suppose you have a class `TableType1` which maps a Table of your db and class `TableType2` which maps another, you could do

```
private void DoStuff(TableType1 item)
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    var items = db.Table<TableType1>();
    // do stuff here...
    db.Close();
}

private void DoStuff(TableType2 item)
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    var items = db.Table<TableType2>();
    // do stuff here...
    db.Close();
}
```

or, alternatively, you could still use generics

```
private void DoStuff<T>() where T : new()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
    var items = db.Table<T>();
    // do stuff here...
    db.Close();
}
```

It depends on your needs, in the first case you have an overload for each type, in the second case you have a single method and the type is specified at higher level

Comment: What is TableType? It isn't used anywhere in SQLite.cs, and Visual Studio doesn't suggest what it might be. I need to call the DoStuff method with any type of table.

Comment: It is just an example. It is a class that models your table, so that each record can be 'mapped' to an object

Comment: But I already have a series of classes that are used to map /define the tables. I need to be able to call the DoStuff method with any one of those classes as a parameter.

Comment: So declare it with generics, why isn't that an option, do you *need*  the `Type` parameter as a runtime variable?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it definitely is an option, i wrote it in the second option

Comment: @Simone - the generics example you gave looks like what I need. Is there a way for me to have two generic parameters in the method signature? I need to pass two tables into the method.

Comment: `void foo<TOne, TTwo>() 
   where TOne : new()
   where TTwo : new()`